# How can i generate a column ( GENERATED ALWAYS) with primary key +10000 in mariadb 10.2.26

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
    ALTER TABLE vouchers 
ADD COLUMN voucher_no DOUBLE 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (id + 100000)
```

> Function or expression 'AUTO_INCREMENT' cannot be used in the GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause of `id`

Here id is primary key.
But this query successfully run on local on mariadb 10.1.37

I have read few articles there i found that mariadb upgrade version doesn't support primary key for generated always.

But i need to create a column for voucher no  like (id +100000) so that we don't need to generate unique voucher no from server side code. I want to save server from created unique voucher no every time new voucher created.
How can i create a column like that?

Comment: You could just use the id as the voucher. If you want it to have 6 digits, let the autoincrement value start with 100000. Or calculate it when you need it (e.g. `select ...., id + 100000 as voucher from ...`)